# How to convert GraphQL schema to JSON and best to GraphQL schema?

Tags: node.js, graphql

I have figured out that this gives me `GraphQLSchema`, which I expect I can convert to JSON. How?

```js
// @flow

import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import {
  buildSchema,
} from 'graphql';

const main = () => {
  const schemaPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../schema.graphql');

  console.log(buildSchema(fs.readFileSync(schemaPath, 'UTF8')));
};

main();
```

And how to do the inverse – how to convert JSON representation of GraphQL schema to GraphQL markup?

One way I have found to do it is:

```js
import {
  printSchema,
  buildSchema,
  buildClientSchema,
  printIntrospectionSchema,
  introspectionFromSchema,
} from 'graphql';

printSchema(buildClientSchema(introspectionFromSchema(buildSchema(fs.readFileSync('./schema.graphql', 'UTF8')))))
```

However, this looses a lot of data, e.g.

```
type Venue implements Node @preLoad {
  # test
  id: ID!
  fuid: String!
  url: String!
  name: String!
  cinema: Cinema!
  futureEventCount: Int!
  globalCinemaVenue: GlobalCinemaVenue
}
```

becomes:

```
type Venue implements Node {
  id: ID!
  fuid: String!
  url: String!
  name: String!
  cinema: Cinema!
  futureEventCount: Int!
  globalCinemaVenue: GlobalCinemaVenue
}
```

Comment: You can use [GotQL](https://github.com/khaosdoctor/gotql/blob/master/README.md) to run queries in JSON and it will take care of converting the data structure to string, send it to the server, and bringing the answer. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: No, I have a literal requirement to convert GraphQL schema language document to JSON and back.

Comment: This was my use case https://github.com/gajus/sort-graphql-sdl. I didn't figure out how to convert to JSON and back, but it turns out I didn't require that for my use case anyway.

Comment: I don't think there's a way you can serialize a GraphQL schema to JSON and back without losing information. Serializing the types is easy enough, but there's no way to capture resolver logic, directives, etc.

Answer (score 7):

You do not need an external library here, you have all you need with `graphql-js` :

```js
import { introspectionFromSchema } from "graphql"
import { GraphQLFileLoader } from "@graphql-tools/graphql-file-loader"
import { loadSchema } from "@graphql-tools/load"

// it can be any source you want here
const schema = loadSchema("./schema.graphql", {
  loaders: [new GraphQLFileLoader()],
})  
const introspection = introspectionFromSchema(schema)

// Tada, you have your introspection
```

Comment: I am using an AWS AppSync compatible graphql schema that using AWS Custom Scalars e.g. AWSDate. How do I bypass this validation and error

Unknown type "AWSDate".
    at assertValidSDL (/Users/czl74b/dev-js/graphql-tools/node_modules/graphql/validation/validate.js:135:11)

Answer (score 4):

You could use the following package which wasn't available at the time of this post I believe: https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-2-json-schema

```
import {
    graphqlSync,
    getIntrospectionQuery,
    IntrospectionQuery
} from 'graphql';

import { fromIntrospectionQuery } from 'graphql-2-json-schema';

const options = {
  ignoreInternals: true,
  nullableArrayItems: true
}

const introspection = graphqlSync(schema, getIntrospectionQuery()).data as IntrospectionQuery;

const jsonSchema = fromIntrospectionQuery(introspection, options);
```

Comment: Have you come across a configuration example with webpack 4? I keep getting `unexpected token ...  no loaders...` for the line `const introspection = graphqlSync(schema, getIntrospectionQuery()).data as IntrospectionQuery;`.